# How to have a biblatex citation in a figure caption appear as such in the list of figures?

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents, citing

At my work place we have an official LaTeX document class that we are supposed to use. I am writing a report using this class and biblatex for my references. It works great, except for one quirk: in the list of figures, citations appearing within captions are replaced by the label of the corresponding bibtex entry. To illustrate, consider the following MWE, with the class file stripped down to the very bare minimum:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{foo1970,
  author =   {Foo, B. and others},
  title =    {Frobtzing the frob},
  journal =      "J.\ Frob.",
  year =     1970}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{mweclass.cls}
\def\fileversion{2.0}
\def\filedate{2010/06/15}
\def\docdate {2010/06/15}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mweclass}[\filedate\space v\fileversion\space MWE class]

\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClassWithOptions{article}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \listoffigures
  \clearpage
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{mweclass}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{test}
  \caption{This cites \textcite{foo1970}.}
\end{figure}

\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered]

\end{document}
```

If I compile this (with `pdflatex`), I get this:

[image: the label appears instead of the text citation]

However, **if I move the `\AtBeginDocument` command out of the class file and I put it right before `\begin{document}`**, I get the expected result:

[image: expected result]

I have tried `\protect`ing the `\textcite` command, but it does not make any difference.

As per @moewe's suggestion, I also tried adding the following snippet to the class file (from his/her answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331867/cite-in-listoffigures-showing-only-the-key-when-not-initialised)):

```
\AtEndPreamble{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \booltrue{citerequest}\relax}%
  \addtocontents{lof}{%
    \booltrue{citerequest}\relax}%
  \addtocontents{lot}{%
    \booltrue{citerequest}\relax}}
```

but unfortunately it makes no difference as long as the `\AtBeginDocument` command appears in the class file (and actually results in some undefined references).

What's up with this? How do I convince `pdflatex` to put the same text in the list of figures and in the figure caption?

Comment: Please check [cite in listoffigures showing only the key when not “initialised”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/331867/35864) and let  us know if the solution there worked for you.

Comment: No, unfortunately it didn't.

Comment: Mhhh, OK. But as far as I understand your question the MWE actually works for you (it did for me when I used a `.bib` file I had on my PC) and it is only with your custom class (which you don't show) that it doesn't work. Please try to isolate which bit of your custom class causes the behaviour as otherwise we will have to resort to speculations not knowing your class at all.

Comment: I completely revised the question and provided a more cogent MWE.

Comment: Don't use `\AtBeginDocument` to insert your `\listoffigures` before you load `biblatex`...

Comment: Unfortunately it's in the document class I must use. I can propose to fix the class, but how do I do that without `\RequirePackage{biblatex}` (which would force all users to use biblatex)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may fix your class using `etoolbox` package (to use `\AtEndPreamble`):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{foo1970,
  author =   {Foo, B. and others},
  title =    {Frobtzing the frob},
  journal =      "J.\ Frob.",
  year =     1970}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{mweclass.cls}
\def\fileversion{2.0}
\def\filedate{2010/06/15}
\def\docdate {2010/06/15}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mweclass}[\filedate\space v\fileversion\space MWE class]

\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClassWithOptions{article}

\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\AtEndPreamble{
  \AtBeginDocument{
    \listoffigures
    \clearpage
  }
}

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{mweclass}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\AtEndPreamble{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \booltrue{citerequest}\relax}%
  \addtocontents{lof}{%
    \booltrue{citerequest}\relax}%
  \addtocontents{lot}{%
    \booltrue{citerequest}\relax}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{test}
  \caption{This cites \protect\textcite{foo1970}.}
\end{figure}

\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works! I had to move around some `\newcolumntype` commands in the original class file and I do not really understand why, but it solved my problem.

Comment: Incidentally, I don't need the `\addtocontents{*}{\booltrue{citerequest}\relax}` commands. It works fine without them.